# Waiting for 2 asynctasks

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask, synchronization

Hello I'm working on a lol appliacation and i have a problem with async tasks and getting data from 2 different json sources . The thing i need to do is get some info from 1 json source(get the hero id) then provide that information to another task to get hero's name (another json source) and then save the info from both sources into an arraylist. I don't know how to make those 2 async task wait for each other and then write down the data. Before i managed to solve this problem's using static fields and saving data from 1 task and then providing it to the second one but im sure there is another way without the need to use fields and i would like to get it done this way for experience as well... Also now i used loopj library but i still cant combine async tasks. And i can't provide you with the lol api key since it supposed to be private but i hope someone will be able to help me anyway. Thanks in advance.

```
    package com.example.lolscouterv2;

import java.io.Console;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.loopj.android.http.*;

public class SummonerGames extends ListActivity {
    String summonerNameId, summonerRegion;
    String finalURL1 = "https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/";
    String finalURL3 =  "/v1.3/game/by-summoner/";
    String finalURL2 = "/recent?api_key=";
    String finalURL;
    JSONArray jsonArray, jArr;
    HashMap <String, String> map;
    JSONObject c1, c2, jArr1, c3;
    String champID = null;
    String champURL1="https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/eune/v1/champion/";
    String champURL2 = "?api_key=";
    String urlChampion;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> summonerGames, summonerChamp;
    static String heroID = null;
    static boolean completed = true;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.summonergames);
        summonerNameId = getIntent().getStringExtra("summonerName");
        summonerRegion = getIntent().getStringExtra("summonerRegion");
        finalURL = finalURL1 + summonerRegion  + finalURL3 + summonerNameId + finalURL2;
        Toast.makeText(SummonerGames.this, finalURL, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        summonerGames = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        final AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get(finalURL, new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(JSONObject response) {
                String kills = null, numOfDeaths = null, assists = null, minions = null;

                try {
                    jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("games");
                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    try {
                        c1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        jArr = c1.getJSONArray("fellowPlayers");
                    } catch (JSONException e1) {

                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    /*for (int j = 0; j < jArr.length(); j++){
                        String testSummonerId = null;
                    try {
                        jArr1 = jArr.getJSONObject(j);
                        //testSummonerId = jArr.getString(2);

                        Log.i("TEST", jArr1.toString());
                    } catch (JSONException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        testSummonerId = jArr1.getString("summonerId");
                        Log.i("TEST222", testSummonerId);
                    } catch (JSONException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.i("ERROR", testSummonerId);
                    Log.i("ERROR2", summonerNameId);
                    if(Integer.parseInt(summonerNameId)== Integer.parseInt(testSummonerId)){
                        try {
                            champID = jArr1.getString("championId");

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }
                    }
                    map.put("heroid", champID);
                    }*/





                    try {
                        c2 = c1.getJSONObject("stats");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        heroID = c1.getString("championId");
                    } catch (JSONException e1) {

                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String level = null;

                    urlChampion = champURL1 + heroID + champURL2;

                    try {
                        level = c2.getString("level");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (c2.isNull("championsKilled")){
                        kills = "0";

                    }
                    else{
                    try {
                        kills = c2.getString("championsKilled");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    }
                    if (c2.isNull("numDeaths"))
                        numOfDeaths = "0";
                    else
                        try {
                            numOfDeaths = c2.getString("numDeaths");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    if (c2.isNull("assists"))
                        assists = "0";
                    else
                        try {
                            assists = c2.getString("assists");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    if (c2.isNull("minionsKilled"))
                        minions = "0";
                    else
                        try {
                            minions = c2.getString("minionsKilled");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    String neutralMinions = null;
                    if (c2.isNull("neutralMinionsKilled")){

                    neutralMinions = "0";
                    }
                    else{
                         try {
                            neutralMinions = c2.getString("neutralMinionsKilled");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    int totalMinions = Integer.parseInt(minions)+ Integer.parseInt(neutralMinions);

                    String gold = null;
                    try {
                        gold = c2.getString("goldEarned");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    float gold1 = Float.parseFloat(gold)/1000; 
                    boolean gameEnd = false;
                    try {
                        gameEnd = c2.getBoolean("win");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String gameResult;

                    if(gameEnd)
                        gameResult = "win";
                    else
                        gameResult = "lose";
                    int x = 0;
                    String data = getChamp(urlChampion);

                    while (completed){
                        x = x + 1;
                        System.out.print(x);

                    }

                    x = 0;

                    map.put ("kills", kills);
                    map.put ("assists", assists);
                    map.put ("deaths", numOfDeaths);
                    map.put ("level", "Level:" + level);
                    map.put("goldEarned", "Gold:" + String.valueOf(gold1) +"k");
                    map.put("gameResult", gameResult);
                    map.put("minions", "Minions:" + String.valueOf(totalMinions));
                    map.put("heroid", data);
                    summonerGames.add(map);
                    completed = true;
                }
                Log.i("test", jsonArray.toString());

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(SummonerGames.this, summonerGames, R.layout.list_items,
                        new String[] { "kills", "assists",
                        "deaths", "goldEarned", "minions", "gameResult", "level", "heroid" }, new int[] { R.id.kills,
                        R.id.assists, R.id.deaths, R.id.gold, R.id.minions, R.id.gameStatus, R.id.heroLevel, R.id.heroName });

                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }

    static public String getChamp(String url){
        AsyncHttpClient client1 = new AsyncHttpClient();



        client1.get(url, new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(JSONObject response1){
                try {
                    heroID = response1.getString("name");
                    Log.i("TESTNAME", heroID);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                completed = false;
            }

        });






        return heroID;

    }
}
```

Comment: Well the default android AsyncTask has an onPostExecute() method, where you could start the second AsyncTask. But since you're using a custom library it will be different.

Comment: i tried doing that but still it didn't work (or i have implemented it in a wrong way) then i solved the problem with a field. This is a new attempt with this library though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run your app on honeycomb and above only, note that AsyncTask runs on a single thread by default, so you can just create and execute the 3 asyncTasks. each will run after another.

if you wish to support older versions of android, you can either customize the current AsyncTask thread pool, or copy the code of AsyncTask :

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/os/AsyncTask.java?av=f

Comment: Yeah but i need to stop the first asynctask until the second one delivers some data to it. I tried using a static variable that both asynctask have access to and a while loop which theoretically should make the the first one wait but it didn't work

Comment: i don't understand. stop the first one before the second one delivers data ? so now the second is the first... maybe you want to use the producer-consumer design-pattern? or maybe chaining of threads tasks? please explain it more clearly. if you want to use a proper waiting, use this (but don't use asyncTasks, it's not for this purpose that they are made for) : http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/thread-signaling.html .

Answer (score 1):

If you are using loopj then the calls are already made async so you do not need to do it yourself. You cannot return **heroId** from your **getChamp()** method because it is initialised in an inner class, **new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){}** in your case. My guess is that your async calls are indeed waiting for each other, but you simply dont get the result back from the second one as per my previous explanation. I suggest you have a look into callback interfaces to see how to use them. What I would do is, create a callback interface and in the **onSuccess** of your call use it to pass the heroId (or any return value) back to your main class. Heres a rough idea:

```
public MyClass implements GetHeroListener{

private GetHeroListener getHeroListener;
public interface GetHeroListener {
    public void getHeroCallback(String heroName);
}

@Override
public void getHeroCallback(String heroName) {
    //here you now get your data from the onSuccess and can do whatever you want example:
    makeNewHTTPCallToGetHeroDetails(myUrl, heroName);
}

static public String getChamp(String url){
    getHeroListener = (GetHeroListener) this; //this is the part where you "connect" your main class to your listner

    AsyncHttpClient client1 = new AsyncHttpClient();

    client1.get(url, new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JSONObject response1){
            try {
                heroID = response1.getString("name");
                getHeroListener.getHeroCallback(heroID); //this is the part where you call the interfaces listener method, it will call back to the class that implements it, just make sure you override the method 
                Log.i("TESTNAME", heroID);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            completed = false;
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: i solved the problem already but thanks for helping anyway :)

Comment: awesome man, glad you managed. Just took a chance anyway, incase someone else might experience similar issues. I understand the frustration haha